# Why does CandyMachine use `cmp_pubkeys` function and not an `Eq` trait?

Tags: metaplex, program, pubkey

CandyMachine program has this function, which is used extensively in the program code:

```
pub fn cmp_pubkeys(a: &Pubkey, b: &Pubkey) -> bool {
    sol_memcmp(a.as_ref(), b.as_ref(), PUBKEY_BYTES) == 0
}
```

However, I do not see, how this is different from simply using `Eq` trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sol_memcmp` syscall is run as native code which is both faster and cheaper than `Eq`/`PartialEq` in eBPF.

You can find the syscall implementation [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/2481ebb1501f1f02937b1b1ea925943254125af2/programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mem_ops.rs#L129).

Comment: After writing a small performance test, it seems like `cmp_pubkeys` function saves 11 compute units for a single call.